# Trouble with Retrofit 2 POST send request

Tags: java, android, post, header, retrofit2

I am sending such a request:

```
@POST("method")
Call<MyObject> reqInfoSend(@Header("token") RequestBody token, @Body RequestBody body);
```

But on the server my @Body comes in header and 
the @Header does not come at all. Is there any idea what to do about it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it right but see there is something wrong with header section as you are passing RequestBody object token .. It should be string

```
@POST("method")
Call<MyObject> reqInfoSend(@Header("token") String token, @Body RequestBody body);
```

Comment: try this if it works then its good otherwise please send me your complete code where you are creating your RequestBody body object and token